# A sequence and majorization

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, majorization

For two positive vectors $a,b$ such that $a\prec b$, we know that there is an $m$ sequence of vectors $c^{(i)}$ such that $$a\prec c^{(1)}\prec \ldots \prec c^{(m)}\prec b$$  where each vector in the precedent formula  differs  from its successor by two entries. This is a classic result.  See
*{A. W. Marshall,I. Olkin, B. C. Arnold, Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications}.* First figure. In the second figure i found a  way  to start from $a$ and arrive at $b$ and  by some «example  verification» i obtained the same sequence $c^{(i)}$ given in the algorithm of the third figure from an article
INEQUALITIES OF KARAMATA, SCHUR AND MUIRHEAD,
AND SOME APPLICATIONS
Zoran Kadelburg, Dusan Dukic, Milivoje Lukic and Ivan Matic
Can someone tell why?

Edit i guess i found the reason.

(Here in figure one   the vector $a$ is $x$ and  $b$ is $y$. $y^*$ is $c^{(m)}$  and $c$ is $c^{(1)}$. If you repeat the  same algorithm applied to $a\prec c^{(m)}$ you obtain $c^{(m-1)}$
until you get $a$); whether if you apply the second (at each step delete the equal entries) you get first $c^{(1)}$ and then repeatedly arrive at $b$ where here the sequence is the same obtained from the third figure algorithm.

[image: The algorithm in books]

---

[image: The algorithm found]

---

[image: The algorithm in the article]

Comment: This does need more detail. There are often many "Robin Hood" moves that can be done from any given vector (you get to choose which two entries to change), and until you specify the rule according to which you make this choice, you don't have a (deterministic) algorithm.

Comment: Hy thanks, the only rule is that two consecutive vectors in the expression differs only by  two entries. If one is familiar with majorization the pretty known result i mentionned let us have $c^{(m)}$  then $c^{(m-1)}$ etc. The trig here i got a way to get from $a$ to $b$ reversely.

Comment: It should be true for any two vectors $a\prec b$. I may put the two algorithms, but if you find a way to build the sequence from $a$ to $b$ as i guess did, after some examples i got the same exact sequence  $c^{(i)}$ given in the books which goes from $b$ to $a$.

Comment: Hence i posted here if someone can manage a transition $a---b$ we can compare the ways and perhaps know why i got the same sequence. In fact this is my goal. As i said the algorithm in the books is pretty known. Let me know if i should explain it. In Z. Kadelburg, D. Duki´c, M. Luki´c and I. Mati´c, Inequalities of Karamata, Schur and Muirhead
and some applications, The Teaching of Mathematics, there is also an algorithm that gives $c^{m)}$ than $c^{(m-1)}$ it is close to the one i mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an algorithm "from big to small", couldn't you obtain an algorithm "from small to big" by replacing the vectors $a$, and $b$ by $x*1-a$ and $x*1-b$ respectively, where $1$ is the vector containing just ones and $x$ is a scalar, larger than the maximum of $a$ and $b$?